# androidx proxyconfig how to set user password authentication

Tags: android, proxy

how to add user password ? my proxy have authentication with user password
code androidx.webkit:1.4.0

```
//my code need to add user password
public void setProxy(){
 if(WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.PROXY_OVERRIDE)) {
            ProxyConfig proxyConfig = new ProxyConfig.Builder()
                . addProxyRule("123.123.123.123:8080")
                . addDirect().build();
            ProxyController.getInstance().setProxyOverride(proxyConfig, new Executor() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Runnable command) {
                        //do nothing
                    }
                }, new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.w(TAG, "WebView");
            
                    }
                });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy to set user password proxy for http or https proxy webview.

```
String user = "xxxx"
String password = "xxxx"
```

But socks proxy can't work this way.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
               @Override
                public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
                   
                    handler.proceed(user, password);
                }
           });
```